# Is there x64 implementation of this Excel VBA function customization dll?

Tags: excel, dll, add-in, vba

I found from internet the following Excel VBA function customization tool by Laurent Longre several years ago:

Homepage:
http://www.xcell.excelabo.net/funcustomize

Download link:
http://www.xcell.excelabo.net/clic?fichier=funcustomize

which is an FUNCUSTOMIZE.DLL  added-in for 32bit (Excel 95 / 97 / 2000 / 2002) versions. This free add-in allows to customize VBA user-defined functions in Excel's function wizard :

- add descriptive text to each argument
- store user-defined functions in a new category (e.g. "FunCustomize demo")

However, there is no source code release and the current added-in usually causes Excel2013 collapse on x64 windows 8.1 platform.

I wonder how can I recreate the same implementation with C/C++/C# so as to modify it for the latest Excel versions and the windows platforms?

Comment: AFAIK, it uses this technique: http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/RegisterUDF00.asp

Comment: It seems the FunCustomeize.dll is more flexible than the implementation in the link.